# I get 404 error when doing a synchronous request to AWS Gateway with Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I created a REST AWS API Gateway and it worked perfectly when it was targeting a single ec2 instance. I then went on to set it up with an EC2 Load Balancer for a Target Group with 2 EC2 instances. Now when I make a request that I synchronously get the status of, I get a 404 error. My guess is that the initial job was posted on one machine and then I try to access it on the other machine yielding a 404 error. I tried to enable stickiness to the target group, but that did nothing. Any suggestions?
[Stickiness config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Gmb.png)

Comment: can you explain a little bit better the situation? So you are starting a job and then you need to get the status of a job, and when you do that, you get a 404, right? Have you checked the logs in your EC2 machines to see which is the exact URL requested?

Comment: Ill check the logs and get back to you.

Comment: @70ny So I send  a request to the api gateway that is setup to target a load balancer with 2 EC2 Instance. The job is received in machine 1. I then try to get the status of that job, and those requests are sent to machine 2. I did getStatus() 2 times, and got 404 errors (this is reflected in the log on machine 2), and on the third getStatus() it went back to machine one and was able to process the job (reflected on machine 1 log)

Comment: @70ny keep in mind this works completely fine when the api gateway points to a single ec2 instance, I only get this problem when I use a Target Group. Also I can eventually complete the job but it keeps bouncing between the two instances, for some reason the stickiness doesnt solve that.

Comment: So, with the load balancer and one single instance, you never face this problem. Right?
Stickiness is connected to a session cookie or value. Are you sure API Gateway is correctly forwarding this configuration from LB to client and from client to LB?

Comment: @70ny I havent tried the load balancer with one instance. Ive tried the api gateway with one instance without the load balancer. Ill try the load balancer with one instance.

Comment: @70ny It works with one instance on the load balancer, but when i add more it breaks.

Comment: Okay, so to me looks like the stickiness cookie is not delivered to the final user.
I would then keep on my investigation in this way: 2 machines on LB and stickiness on. Clear your cookie / cache and connect to LB and note down the response of set-cookie. Then do the same through API Gateway. Do you notice any difference? My guess is that the stickiness cookie is somehow blocked from API Gateway, and so for the LB you're always a new user.

Comment: @70ny thanks for the reply, Ill give that a shot. Im sorry for my delayed response, but im only an intern so my hours are limited.

Comment: No problem! When you've more to share, I'm here to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to **check the logs on your EC2 instances** and see which is the exact request routed from the LB to the EC2 machine. My experience is that LB calls the EC2 instances using their internal IP address and the URL might be modified, based on configuration.

Checking the logs will help you debug this error. With stickness you're doing good.